# Não consigo redirecionar para uma nova uma aba dentro da mesma url

Tags: php

Sou iniciante em PHP e estou com dificuldades pra conseguir achar uma solução pro meu problema. 
Tenho um *array* principal com 7 *arrays*, com 2 campos cada, que são abas numa das urls do site.

Preciso que ao clicar no botão 'próxima etapa' seja redirecionado para a segunda aba, mas não consegui fazer nem por *json* nem por javascript. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Segue abaixo parte do código.

```
$topicos = array(
    array(
        "id"    => 1,
        "label" => "Formação"
    ),
    array(
        "id"    => 2,
        "label" => "Cursos Extra Curriculares"
    ),
    array(
        "id"    => 3,
        "label" => "Experiências Profissionais"
    ),
    array(
        "id"    => 4,
        "label" => "Experiências Internacionais"
    ),
    array(
        "id"    => 5,
        "label" => "Idiomas"
    ),
    array(
        "id"    => 6,
        "label" => "Conhecimentos Técnicos Específicos"
    ),
    array(
        "id"    => 7,
        "label" => "Outras Informações"
    )
); 

<form action="<?= $path ?>banco_de_talentos_add_2" id="segundo_formulario" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" id="proxima" name="proxima" value="0"/>

<div class="row-fluid ">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="dropdown_protect"></div>
        <div class="tab-header">
            <ul id="tab-content" class="nav nav-tabs classe_a_ocultar_em_smartphone classe_a_ocultar_em_tablet">
                <?php
                foreach ($topicos as $t):
                    if($t["id"] == 1):
                        echo "<li class='active'><a href='#tab" . $t["id"] . "'>" . $t["label"] . "</a></li>";
                    else:
                        echo "<li><a id='ir_para_questionario' href='#tab" . $t["id"] . "'>" . $t["label"] . "</a></li>";
                    endif;
                endforeach;
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div><!--tab-header-->

        <div class="tab-content">
            <?php foreach($topicos as $t):
                if($t["id"] == 1):
                    echo '<div id="tab' . $t["id"] . '" class="tab-pane active">';
                else:
                    echo '<div id="tab' . $t["id"] . '" class="tab-pane">';
                endif;

                include "banco_de_talentos_formulario_" . $t["id"] . ".php";

                echo '</div>';
            endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="width:100%;text-align:center">
    <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn"/>
    <input type="button" id="btn_anterior" value="Etapa Anterior" class="btn" onClick="document.getElementById('proxima').value = 2; document.getElementById('segundo_formulario').submit()"/>
    <input type="button" id="btn_proxima" value="Próxima Etapa" class="btn" onClick="document.getElementById('proxima').value = 1; document.getElementById('segundo_formulario').submit()"/>
   <!-- <input type=button value="Proxima aba" class="btn" id="new_tab" onkeydown="tab()"> -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dê uma olhada nesse JSFiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/o47v8La9/

Fiz um sistema de abas que dá para você entender.

HTML

```
<div id="tabs">
    <span class="tab" id="#php"> PHP </span>
    <span class="tab" id="#html"> HTML </span>
    <span class="tab" id="#js"> JS </span>
</div>

<div id="php" class="main"> Teste Aba PHP </div>
<div id="html" class="main"> Teste Aba HTML </div>
<div id="js" class="main"> Teste Aba JS </div>
```

Note que no código acima criei 3 abas. Cada uma delas tem um ID.

E depois embaixo criei 3 divs com o mesmo ID da aba, mas sem a **#**.

Depois no JS com jQuery...

```
$('.tab').click(function(){
    $('.main').hide();

    var tabSelecionada = $(this).prop('id');

    $(tabSelecionada).show();
});
```

A primeira linha é a função do click no elemento da aba, nos Links por assim dizer. 
Quando clico em um deles, a função esconde todas as abas (na segunda linha) e depois mostra apenas que foi selecionada (na quinta linha).

Agora é só implementar no seu código, caso sirva.

Comment: Obrigado, mas eu preciso colocar essa mudança de abas para o evento onclick, no botão próxima etapa. Toda vez que eu clicar no botão próxima etapa, ele redireciona para a próxima aba. Você poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Então, é a mesma ideia...

Comment: Usei a mesma idéia, só alterando para os nomes das classes que eu tenho, mas ainda assim não consegui. Em outra página do site, foi feitoa mesma coisa, só que com duas abas, clico no botão e redireciono para outra aba...